# HTML CSS Dynamic number of DIVs side by side in a container with dynamic height per div

Tags: css, html, formatting

Hello I am trying to create a row layout of `div`s.

Unknown known number of `div`s per row.  Could be 1 could be 25.

I used a table layout `display: table;` because it seems to be the only way to get equal sizes for all 'div's on the row, without knowing their sizes and with no wrapping of `div`s when the page shrinks.

How would I do this same thing but have the `div`s height also be dynamic.

I am trying to avoid the old layout technique of using tables and using tables in tables to fix something like this.

Here is an example in jdFiddle.  As you can see Row 2 Column 1 has extra lines but every cell on that row has grown to match it.

http://jsfiddle.net/djlerman/G9dgQ/2/

CSS:

```
#row {
  display:            table;
  table-layout:       fixed;
  width:              95%;
  margin:             0 auto;
}

#row div {
  display:            table-cell;
}

.column {
  border:             1px solid;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius:      15px;
  border-color:       grey;
  box-shadow:         grey 1em 1em 1em
  -webkit-gradient:   grey 1em 1em 1em
  -moz-linear-gradient: grey 1em 1em 1em
  margin:             0 auto;
  padding:            5px;
  text-align:         center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="row">
  <div class="column">
    Column 1
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Column 2
  </div>
</div> 

<div id="row">
  <div class="column">
    Column 1
    <br />Line 1<br />Line 2<br />Line 3<br />Line 4<br />Line 5<br />Line 6<br />Line 7<br />
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Column 2
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Column 3
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Column 4
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Column 5
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Column 6
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Column 7
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Column 8
  </div>
</div> 


<div id="row">
  <div class="column">
    Column 1
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Column 2
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Column 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks,

~Donavon

+-------------------------------------------------------------------+

Tried to give an answer to what I figured but it wont let me post and answer.  So here it is...

Jeeze.   This 'div' stuff is crazy complicated.  :-(

Here is what I came up with. Thanks to the responses I got and LOTS of googleing.

Hope it can help others:

http://jsfiddle.net/djlerman/G9dgQ/5/

CSS:

```
  .row {
      display: table;
      table-layout: fixed;
      width: 95%;
      margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .row div {
      display: table-cell;
  }
  .column {
      border: 0px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 0px;
      text-align: center;
      overflow: auto;
      vertical-align: top;
  }
  .border {
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid;
      -moz-border-radius: 15px;
      border-radius: 15px;
      border-color: grey;
      border-color: grey;
      box-shadow: grey .25em .25em .25em;
      -webkit-gradient: grey .25em .25em .25em;
      -moz-linear-gradient: grey .25em .25em .25em;
      vertical-align: top;
      text-align: center;
      overflow: auto;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 1000px;
      max-width: 1000px;
  }
  .columnSpace {
      width: 10px;
  }
  .rowSpace {
      height: 10px;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="border">Column 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="columnSpace"></div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="border">Column 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="rowSpace"></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="border">Column 1
            <br />Line 1
            <br />Line 2
            <br />Line 3
            <br />Line 4
            <br />Line 5
            <br />Line 6
            <br />Line 7
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="columnSpace"></div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="border">Column 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="columnSpace"></div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="border">Column 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="columnSpace"></div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="border">Column 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="columnSpace"></div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="border">Column 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="columnSpace"></div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="border">Column 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="columnSpace"></div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="border">Column 7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="columnSpace"></div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="border">Column 8</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="rowSpace"></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="border">Column 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="columnSpace"></div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="border">Column 2
            <br />Line 1
            <br />Line 2
            <br />Line 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="columnSpace"></div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="border">Column 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: should column3 in row2 float undenith column2? (id="row" should be class="row", because you need it more than once)

Comment: That's a good point.

So in the style section #row would be changed to .row

Would #row div{} be changed to .row div{}?  How would these work together as class?

Comment: just like that you can also write .row .column{} because if your write .row div{xx} every div inside row gets xx styles

Comment: I tried a few things but the floating point seems to be very hard, don't know if it is possible. in your css where you got .column your forgot the ; (semikolons) after all styles with em. as soon as you add them the shadows will work.

Comment: Thank you...  I changed the row to a class and fixed the shadows.  I was wondering where the shadows went.

Answer (score 1):

It seems SO will let me post an answer to this now, so I am putting the answer in the answer section.

Jeeze.   This 'div' stuff is crazy complicated.  :-(

Here is what I came up with. Thanks to the responses I got and LOTS of googleing.

Hope it can help others:

http://jsfiddle.net/djlerman/G9dgQ/5/

CSS:

```
  .row {
      display: table;
      table-layout: fixed;
      width: 95%;
      margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .row div {
      display: table-cell;
  }
  .column {
      border: 0px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 0px;
      text-align: center;
      overflow: auto;
      vertical-align: top;
  }
  .border {
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid;
      -moz-border-radius: 15px;
      border-radius: 15px;
      border-color: grey;
      border-color: grey;
      box-shadow: grey .25em .25em .25em;
      -webkit-gradient: grey .25em .25em .25em;
      -moz-linear-gradient: grey .25em .25em .25em;
      vertical-align: top;
      text-align: center;
      overflow: auto;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 1000px;
      max-width: 1000px;
  }
  .columnSpace {
      width: 10px;
  }
  .rowSpace {
      height: 10px;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="border">Column 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="columnSpace"></div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="border">Column 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="rowSpace"></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="border">Column 1
            <br />Line 1
            <br />Line 2
            <br />Line 3
            <br />Line 4
            <br />Line 5
            <br />Line 6
            <br />Line 7
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="columnSpace"></div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="border">Column 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="columnSpace"></div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="border">Column 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="columnSpace"></div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="border">Column 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="columnSpace"></div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="border">Column 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="columnSpace"></div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="border">Column 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="columnSpace"></div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="border">Column 7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="columnSpace"></div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="border">Column 8</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="rowSpace"></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="border">Column 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="columnSpace"></div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="border">Column 2
            <br />Line 1
            <br />Line 2
            <br />Line 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="columnSpace"></div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="border">Column 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G9dgQ/3/)**

Here are the relevant changes to your CSS:

```
  #row {
    display:            block;
    table-layout:       fixed;
    width:              95%;
    margin:             0 auto;
    white-space:        nowrap;
  }

  #row div {
    display:            inline-block;
    vertical-align:     top;
  }
```

**What this does**

The `table-cell` display is going to (surprise) make the div behave like a td.  Really, what you want is an `inline-block`.  I've updated the CSS to reflect this, and changed the `#row` container to a simple block display.  Then, I set the vertical alignment of the child divs to the top, which is necessary because (by default) the browser wants to align inline content to the baseline (the text bottom) of the container.

Adding the `white-space: nowrap;` prevents the divs from breaking when they expand beyond their container, which should solve that issue as well.

This should address your problem adequately.

---

**UPDATE 2**

[Here's a flexbox approach;](http://jsfiddle.net/G9dgQ/4/)

This will preserve the expansion of the row to fill available space like you were talking about in the comments.

Comment: Sweet.  This is great!!!

The only thing is the row above and the row below lost their formatting.  They are no longer spreading out to fill the row.

Comment: Perhaps what you need then is a `flex-box`. [CSS Flexbox Demo](http://demo.agektmr.com/flexbox/)

Comment: Looks interesting but I don't think the Flexbox model is standard enough yet for me to be able to use with the current project.

P.S. The 2nd jsFiddle example you supplied doesn't have the 1st and 3rd rows expanding out. So I can't see how that part fits together